# Update label phone number in Address Book

Tags: ios, xcode, addressbook

Help. I want to do a simple application to update ALL Phone Labels to another specific. I need to change all (work, home, iphone) to "Sync".

I tried to do this, but didn't work. Somebody can help me, please?

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
//ABRecordRef record = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBookRef, ABRecordGetRecordID(record));

//NSString *addressBookNum;
NSString *phoneNumber;
NSString *tagLabel;


if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {

    });
}
else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {

    CFErrorRef *error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex numberOfPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {

        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );

        ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

        [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];

        for (CFIndex k = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers); k++) {

            phoneNumber = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, k);
            tagLabel = (__bridge NSString*) ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phoneNumbers, k);

            CFStringRef newTagLabel = (CFStringRef)@"Sync";

            ABMultiValueReplaceLabelAtIndex(phoneNumbers, newTagLabel, k);

            ABAddressBookSave(person, (CFErrorRef *) error);

            }

        }



}
else {
    // Send an alert telling user to change privacy setting in settings app
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your statement

```
ABAddressBookSave(person, (CFErrorRef *) error);
```

The function `ABAddressBookSave`  is defined as

```
bool ABAddressBookSave (
   ABAddressBookRef addressBook,
   CFErrorRef *error
);
```

So the 1st argument is a reference to the address book, not to a person record.
You had to save the address book after you have done all of your changes.

**EDIT** (due to your comment below):

The error message means that you are trying to apply function `ABMultiValueReplaceLabelAtIndex(...)` to a **non-mutable** record, as `phoneNumbers` is. It is non-mutable even if you assign it to a reference of type `ABMutableMultiValueRef`! You had to create first a **mutable** copy using something like

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef mutablePhoneNumbers = ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy(phoneNumbers);
```

Only than can the label be changed.
Independently of this, my first argument still applies, and you had to save the changes of your address book at the end.

Comment: Hello Reinhard. Thanks for the quick answer, but I get an error in the line above:

  ABMultiValueReplaceLabelAtIndex(phoneNumbers, newTagLabel, k);

I got this error:
Assertion failed: (((ABCMultiValue *)multiValue)->flags.isMutable), function ABMultiValueReplaceLabelAtIndex, file /SourceCache/AddressBook_Sim/AddressBook-10898.7/ABMultiValue.c, line 124.